How to store all key/values of a dictionary in a single line to store?
This is the sample code:
my_list = [
    {'name': 'Saeed', 'source_country': 'IR', 'destination_country': 'IT', 'email': 'sample1@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Vahid', 'source_country': 'US', 'destination_country': 'DE', 'email': 'sample2@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Ali', 'source_country': 'UK', 'destination_country': 'JP', 'email': 'sample3@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Joe', 'source_country': 'FR', 'destination_country': 'KR', 'email': 'sample4@gmail.com'},
]
html = '\n'.join([f"<p>{b.replace('_', ' ').title()}: {p[b]}</p>" for p in my_list for b in p])

This is current output:
>>> print(html)
<p>Name: Saeed</p>
<p>Source Country: IR</p>
<p>Destination Country: IT</p>
<p>Email: sample1@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Vahid</p>
<p>Source Country: US</p>
<p>Destination Country: DE</p>
<p>Email: sample2@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Ali</p>
<p>Source Country: UK</p>
<p>Destination Country: JP</p>
<p>Email: sample3@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Joe</p>
<p>Source Country: FR</p>
<p>Destination Country: KR</p>
<p>Email: sample4@gmail.com</p>

I'm going to have this (expected output):
<p>Name: Saeed, Source Country: IR, Destination Country: IT, Email: sample1@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Vahid, Source Country: US, Destination Country: DE, Email: sample2@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Ali, Source Country: UK, Destination Country: JP, Email: sample3@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Joe, Source Country: FR, Destination Country: KR, Email: sample4@gmail.com</p>

How can I store and print the expected output?
Edit1
I know this way to save the output, but I don't mean it:
html = '\n'.join([f"<p>Name: {p['name']}, Source Country: {p['source_country']}, Destination Country: {p['destination_country']}, Email: {p['email']}</p>" for p in my_list])


@trazoM Please don't post answers as comments. Write an answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment "When shouldn't I comment? Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);"

my_list = [{'name': 'Saeed', 'source_country': 'IR', 'destination_country': 'IT', 'email': 'sample1@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Vahid', 'source_country': 'US', 'destination_country': 'DE', 'email': 'sample2@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Ali', 'source_country': 'UK', 'destination_country': 'JP', 'email': 'sample3@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Joe', 'source_country': 'FR', 'destination_country': 'KR', 'email': 'sample4@gmail.com'}]

with open('output_data.txt', 'a') as fd:
    for d in my_list:
        text = ', '.join([f"{k.replace('_', ' ').title()}: {v}" for k,v in d.items()])
        print(text)
        fd.write(f"<p>{text}</p>\n")

Output:
<p>Name: Saeed, Source Country: IR, Destination Country: IT, Email: sample1@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Vahid, Source Country: US, Destination Country: DE, Email: sample2@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Ali, Source Country: UK, Destination Country: JP, Email: sample3@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Joe, Source Country: FR, Destination Country: KR, Email: sample4@gmail.com</p>

Saved in:
output_data.txt

UPD1: one-liner without save:
html = '\n'.join([f"<p>{', '.join([f"{k.replace('_', ' ').title()}: {v}" for k,v in d.items()])}</p>" for d in my_list])
print(html)

Output:
<p>Name: Saeed, Source Country: IR, Destination Country: IT, Email: sample1@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Vahid, Source Country: US, Destination Country: DE, Email: sample2@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Ali, Source Country: UK, Destination Country: JP, Email: sample3@gmail.com</p>
<p>Name: Joe, Source Country: FR, Destination Country: KR, Email: sample4@gmail.com</p>


I know the way you wrote the code, but I didn't mean it.

Your question is: "How can I store and print the expected output?"

That is how you can "store/save" and print the output.

You may be right based on my question. I'll edit that part of question to clarify.

Can you remove the downvote then please, as I did try to help and answer your question.

I changed it to upvote, thanks. But it's not necessary to save to a file. Saving to memory is enough in most answers and for yourself (to have no tmp files in the future on your PC/laptop).

If you want flexible one-liner code without saving it, then I've updated my answer.
